# How should i set default focus to my first Text-box in asp:repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asprepeater

I already read all the questions related to it .

My aspx contain code as follows

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptAnswer" OnItemDataBound="rptAnswerTextBox_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="AnswerTextBox" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and on aspx.cs  I handled it in following way

```
     rptAnswer.DataSource = dt;
    rptAnswer.DataBind();
    if (rptAnswer.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)(rptAnswer.Items[0].FindControl("AnswerTextBox"));
        txt1.Focus();

    }
```

It is giving compilation error as

```
    'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'Focus' and no extension method 'Focus' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

So, How should i set default focus to my first Text-box in repeater?, 
I achieved it through Java-script, But I want it through c# code.

Comment: @fubo - but no any solution working

Comment: I don't have that much reputation to comment their, so i raised a seprate question

Comment: compilation error? your code looks correct

Comment: @Mysterio11 - yes, its compilation error

Comment: You are sure that your textbox is of type System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox, if it is then it should have Focus method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.focus(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Hemant Dhake - i will check it